# Prevent sequelize from generating foreign key by default on belongsTo associations

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a self referential relationship (not important)

```
export default class Person{
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  public id!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Person, "parent_id")
  parent!: Person;

  @HasMany(() => Person, "parent_id")
  children!: Person;

}
```

When I sync, sequelize creates a foreign key relationship automatically

I don't want it to do that since the data is incomplete and some Persons may have parents that are not in the database.
How do I **prevent** sequelize from generating  by default

> By default the foreign key for a belongsTo relation will be generated
> from the target model name and the target primary key name.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.
Implement:

```
@HasMany(() => Person, "parent_id")
  children!: Person;
```

Not with sequelize-typescript but with the core https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html may do the job. Just don't implement foreign keys at the model but only for the typescript compiler.

Using constraints: false, will prevent foreign key creation.
I don't know if you can implement it at sequelize-typescript package